# Can a variable passed by value have its value changed? (In C)

Tags: c, memory-management

I was calling a function, whose prototype was `int foo(int device, double *x, double *y)`
And I was calling it like this `foo(dev, (double*)x, (double*)y);`, where x and y are both pointers to floats.

For some reason device was entering the function as 1 and exiting as a random huge value.

Was is possible that because foo dealt with doubles and I passed in floats it messed with their memory?

Comment: you aren't getting the pointers of `x` and `y`, you are casting them to a pointer.

Comment: What you did was tell the compiler that x and y point to floats, which was effectively a lie. Consequently, the C language standard will say your program has "undefined behavior". It's liable to do anything.

Comment: Making casts to silence compiler warnings can lead to...

Comment: "...  exiting as a random huge value." Post code that shows device's new value.

Comment: Normally, there wouldn't be a problem.  However, you told untruths to the compiler about what you're passing, and the compiler trusted you — you made the casts, which say "trust me; I know what I'm doing" — and then wrote in places you didn't expect because you didn't really know what you were doing.  And as a side-effect of writing where you didn't expect it to, your `dev` variable got trampled.  You can't pass `float *` as a `double *` and expect anything to work well — unless your function 'undoes' the erroneous cast, which would be extremely weird.  Get the types right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> For some reason device was entering the function as 1 and exiting as a random huge value.

What happened is likely *worse* than that.

You told the system that you were passing pointers to elements of, say, *eight* bytes - but those elements were only *four* bytes in size.

So the called function, writing to one of the elements whose pointer it received, actually overwrote two elements (if available). And if no element was available to receive the value...

This kind of thing results in "undefined behaviour" - literally anything may happen (very rarely, the program even works, and no one knows why - so "but it works!" shouldn't reassure).

I suspect that you had allocated both dev and x on the stack as temporary variables:

```
float x[2];
int dev;
```

At that point, the address of x was pointing inside the caller's stack, where also dev resided. The call prototype mismatch resulted in the overwriting of dev **and who knows what else**. **Even if you had not passed dev as a parameter, it would have be overwritten all the same**.

Comment: That was it, thank you! I guess in C you really have to be careful with what you do.

Comment: Not in C alone :-) but yes, you have. I routinely keep *all* warnings enabled and advise you to do the same. Also, you may find the `valgrind` utility useful to debug hard-to-find memory errors.